# Is there way to invoke a lambda function if an amazon s3 object is accessed?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am hosting a javascript file in an amazon s3 bucket . Whenever the .js file is accessed, an event must be invoked and the lambda function must execute? Is there some way to know if an object in the s3 bucket is accessed? Not created but just accessed.

Comment: One way to do this is to use API Gateway to proxy all S3 calls for the objects of interest. See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/integrating-api-with-aws-services-s3.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not one of the available events for Lambda to hook into.

You might be able to hook up something using S3 access logging - log the accesses to another bucket, and have a Lambda function process the resulting log files - but it will not be real-time by any stretch of the imagination.

Comment: yes, make sure it is logged into another bucket otherwise you might run into 'infinite loop' issue if not careful

Answer (score 1):

FYI - this is now available by creating triggers on s3 buckets that can launch a lambda function.

Comment: To elaborate you want to enable cloudtrail, then set up an cloudwatch event rule on object level, have it listen for getobject calls on your bucket, make this rule trigger your lambda. Boom. No long polling required.