# S3 bucket automatically in snowflake

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have an question Here. When am trying to load from S3 bucket it was loading old files also in S3 bucket. Is there any current option is there in copy command
Ex, copy into table from @table_json.
Is there any option is there to archive old data in S3 bucket in snowflake

Pls help if there is an options

Comment: Are you looking for a way to purge the already loaded files from S3 bucket?

Comment: Snowflake load "all files" that are in the PATH and match the PATTERN. But it will not load files twice (if the named file has not changed). But having large lists to filter on snowflake side is "slow" so normally you don't load with large wildcard paths.

Comment: @srinath menon if we purge all the files deleted in bucket. It should not get deleted it should be archived automatically to new folder

Comment: I believe what you are looking for is a new feature. The way currently it works is that if you use "purge=true" then the files from the stage and the storage. If it is false then these files are retained.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no option to move files to another path after they have been loaded using a COPY statement.

Other options to consider

- load files directly into the S3 archive location, set up Lambda functions to copy new files to a dedicated "load" location. When running the COPY function in Snowflake specify the PURGE option to delete files in the "load" location after they have been loaded.
- use Snowpipe to automatically load new files

Answer (score 0):

If I understand clearly you want to archive them to a different folder after COPY statement is executed.

I can think of this option.

- You have to set up access logging for your S3 bucket used for COPY command.
- Then set up a Lambda trigger event  on the Access logging buckets' object creation process
- It will not be real time but that is what we want.

Hope this helps. Just an idea from my side. Please let me know

[Is there way to invoke a lambda function if an amazon s3 object is accessed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30304338/is-there-way-to-invoke-a-lambda-function-if-an-amazon-s3-object-is-accessed)